# How can I test what is slowing down my php code?

Tags: php, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php-cgi running very slowly on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687634/php-cgi-running-very-slowly-on-windows)

I'm running wordpress on a windows server, and for some reason the php code is executing very slowly. How would I be able to trace exactly the part of the code that is slowing the server down?

Comment: are you sure that it is PHP? you could try firefox extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/

Comment: used yslow, but didnt help very much. i know the issue is server side, and has nothing to do with latency (had a godaddy rep help me with that one). any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Try to start with `xdebug` php extension. It could give you a lot of information.

Comment: @Rob: have you examined what `xdebug` is?

Comment: yes, im looking at it now... but keep in mind i have very limited knowledge of php

Comment: should i simply install it on my server?

Comment: @Rob: I have a lot of things to keep in mind. Your skills is not priority thing for me, unfortunately.

Comment: @Rob: yes, you need to install it at least to start using it.

Comment: i dont know how to even get started with this installation process, pretty much the entire documentation is way over my head. is there a simpler debugger?

Comment: @Rob: debug (especially solving performance issues) is not an easy process

Comment: i tried adding zend_extension="C:\xdebug.dll" to my php.ini and it didnt make any difference. should i copy the dll to my ext folder instead?

Comment: are there any other debuggers that install easily on a windows server?

Comment: @Rob: if you cannot even plug it in - then I can assure you that you'll not be able to debug application.

Comment: What im actually trying to do is figure out which extension is slowing down the script and change the configuration on my server accordingly. I suspect it is URL Rewrite Module 2.0, but just need some sort of a confirmation before I start drastically changing the setup on my server. I fully acknowledge that i do not have the expertise to actually debug any of the php code

Comment: @Rob: well, I can bet beer that you will not be able to do that.